# Enabling AJAX on Contact Form 7 Form after AJAX Load

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, contact-form-7

I've tried searching but this only returns results on how to AJAX load a page/form.
What I am doing is loading a form via AJAX (Contact Form 7) and I would like to know how to re-enable AJAX submission on that form. Is this a possibility with CF7?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Contact Form 7 calls an init function, which executes on page load. If your form is loading using AJAX, you should make sure that the function gets called after your form is loaded.

Look into:

`plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js`

for the definition of the function `wpcf7InitForm`.

**Edit:**
Calling this function inserts a new loading logo each time. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a better solution than deleting the duplicate loader from DOM using jQuery:

```
function initContactForm() {
    jQuery('div.wpcf7 > form').wpcf7InitForm();
    jQuery('form.wpcf7-form')
        .each(function() {
            $j(this).find('img.ajax-loader').last().remove();
        });
}
```

Comment: Good job. For those interested, this fixed my problem too by calling the `wpcf7InitForm()` function after my ajax load (`$('div.wpcf7 > form').wpcf7InitForm();`).

Comment: Awesome, just what I was looking for!

Comment: I've tried this solution and it sort of works. I say sort of since you need to a) call it every time you close then open the popup and b) each call inserts a new loading logo

Comment: @Andrija, have you found a solution for not cloning the loading logos?

Comment: @rafaelmsantos Unfortunately, no smart solution - I've basically added a check that removes unnecessary elements from the DOM after they were added with the library

Comment: @Andrija, I see. I've done something similar too, thanks for your comment.

Comment: #kevin i check $('div.wpcf7 > form').wpcf7InitForm(); but it not working validation for form

Comment: For some reason it's remove my ajax-loader even if it was one element for fix that I added condition: 
    if ( jQuery('.ajax-loader').length > 1 ) {
      jQuery( 'form.wpcf7-form' )
        .each(function() {
            jQuery(this).find('.ajax-loader').last().remove();
        });
    }

Answer (score 9):

this behavior changed with version 4.8 of wpcf7. since then the call would be

```
wpcf7.initForm( jQuery('.wpcf7-form') );
```

while it does not require jQuery anymore, you could also pass a node..
somehting like this (capable of multiple forms..)

```
var wpcf7_form = document.getElementsByClassName('wpcf7-form');
[].forEach.call(wpcf7_form, function( form ) {
  wpcf7.initForm( form );
});
```

it is still written in jQuery, but it does not have to be active (i.e. jQuery.ready()) in your function to operate. plus it got rid of jQuery.form

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer for latest versions of WPCF7

Answer (score 8):

Use the following code for version 5.4 or above:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".wpcf7 > form").forEach((
                function(e){
                    return wpcf7.init(e)
                }
            )
        );
```

Put this in your ajax response. This will re-initialize all forms

Answer (score 2):

I spent the last three hours looking for a solution to this and I only have found questions without answer, but I think I found a solution and hope this will help you and other people with this problem.

In my case, i was trying to embed a CF7 form in an inline lightbox with PrettyPhoto (but I think this is the same with others like Fancybox). My problem was that these inline lightboxes works generating the content inside the lightbox via AJAX, and the CF7 scripts were loaded before that content, so the AJAX submit of the form wasn't work.

What I did was getting the CF7 scripts via jQuery.get on the event triggered when a prettyphoto lightbox is opened. In your case, I think you should do this just after generating the content via AJAX, something like:

```
jQuery.get("/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/jquery.form.min.js?ver=3.51.0-2014.06.20");
jQuery.get("/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/js/scripts.js?ver=4.1.1");
```

Make sure that your paths and versions are the same, otherwise change them.

This will refresh the form and re-enable the AJAX submit.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Was unable to send the form via ajax with the above comments. I had to use the `wpcf7.submit` method vs `wpcf7.init`

Example usage:

```
wpcf7.submit(document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form'));
```